# How can I drag tabs in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am trying to create a JTabbedPane with tabs arranged vertically LEFT with SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT. The code snippet for this is as below:

```
private Component createTabbedPane() 
{
 JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT,
  JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  JPanel pane = new JPanel();
  pane.add(new JLabel("This is Panel " + i));
  tabbedPane.addTab("Tab " + i, pane);
 }
 return tabbedPane;
}
```

However, I want have the same scrolling feature with mouse dragged so that it could be used for touch screen. Is there any way to use mouse listeners on the tabs?

Comment: This would be helpful to you.
Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269/how-to-implement-draggable-tab-using-java-swing and http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/04/drag-and-drop-tabs-in-jtabbedpane.html. Fist link is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can add mouseListners to the tabs themselves or to the tab components.

Comment: I tried by overriding the processMouseEvent and processMouseMotionEvent method for mouse drag. It works fine for a jtable, but not working for jtabbedpane. Which method should I need to modify to get this dragging behavior?

Comment: Hi I tried the following:<br>protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    switch (e.getID()) {
    case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED:
     startPoint = e.getPoint();
     break;
    }
    super.processMouseEvent(e);
   } <br

Comment: protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
     Rectangle r = getVisibleRect();
     Point p = e.getPoint();
     int dx = (startPoint.x - p.x);
     int dy = (startPoint.y - p.y);
     Rectangle aRect = new Rectangle(r.x + dx, r.y + dy, r.width
       + dx, r.height + dy);
     scrollRectToVisible(aRect);
    }
   }

Comment: It is not allowing me to put the code in order, am I doing it correctly?

Comment: the code is not formatted, this text box is not allowing to format the code the way i did in the first post; but these are the two methods I override for dragging. with these two methods the dragging is not working [it works for a jtable]. can you please tell me where i am going wrong?