# How do I make tabs in a JTabbedPane rearrangeable?

Tags: java

I want to be able to move my tabs in my jTabbedPane left or right to change the sorting order. I looked around but I noticed most of what I found is asking how to drag and drop a tab in. I just want to make it resortable so that I can move the rightmost tab to the left of the leftmost tab or any order I want.

I know for table columns in a JTable, there is a method, something along the lines of

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.setReordering(false); //disables reordering of columns
```

which prevents this so this functionality is already enabled with columns in tables but with tabs in JTabbedPanes, I cannot find any method similar to this but I'm thinking it would be something similar like

```
tab.setReordering(true)
```

as well but I don't see anything.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376084/how-can-i-drag-tabs-in-jtabbedpane If this fixes your issue please let me/us know and I/we can mark your question as a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A quick search](https://coderanch.com/t/342692/java/JTabbedPane-Tab-Reordering), yielded that it doesn't seem to be supported by Swing directly.

Though this is fairly common with GUI frameworks, where you are often left to implement certain functionality yourself (e.g. I recently had to manually implement TreeCell to allow context menus on TreeItems). This prevents libraries from becoming monolithic unmaintainable messes.

You can find an implementation of the drag-and-drop functionality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269/how-to-implement-draggable-tab-using-java-swing)