# How can a drag a tab into a new window with Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, tabs

Is there a way that I can have a tabbed application, where if i drag a tab off the window, it opens that panel in a new frame?

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you will have to post a bit of source code, to see what you have done so far. I found this link that maybe is interesting to you:

http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/04/drag-and-drop-tabs-in-jtabbedpane.html

It explain how to drag and drop tabs, maybe you can apply the same principle to your idea.

Also in this forum there is a similar question, maybe you wanna have a look:

[How to implement draggable tab using Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269/how-to-implement-draggable-tab-using-java-swing)