# Reordering tabs in a JTabbedPane in java

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Is there a way to swap two tabs?

I have a touchscreen monitor with a java app with four tabs:

Silkscreen Prep 1, Silkscreen Prep 2, Silkscreen 1, Silkscreen 2

and I want to swap Silkscreen Prep 2 and Silkscreen one so that a worker on the left side can easily just use silkscreen prep one and silkscreen one and the worker on the right can use silkscreen prep 2 and silkscreen 2.

Comment: I don't know if I really understand your issue. Tabs are odered in the way they are added to the JTabbedPane.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269/how-to-implement-draggable-tab-using-java-swing

Comment: Not duplicate. I don't want to implement drag-and-drop. I want to reorder them in code.

Comment: @Howard. I want to be able to swap them once they have been added.

Comment: @Howard: I defer to @dah's requirements, but the link migth still be a useful alternative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in [*How to Use Tabbed Panes*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), [`TabComponentsDemo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TabComponentsDemo) shows how to dynamically change tabs. Simply add them in your preferred order.